# Hibernate и уровни изоляциии транзакций

Tags: java, hibernate, транзакции

Есть два тестовых метода:

```
@GetMapping("/test1")
@Transactional
public void test1() throws InterruptedException {
    Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
    Test test = session.get(Test.class, 1l);
    test.setBalance(100);
    session.update(test);
    Thread.sleep(15000);
}

@GetMapping("/test2")
@Transactional
public void test2() {
    Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
    Test test = session.get(Test.class, 1l);
    session.delete(test);
}
```

Первым вызывается test1(). В текущей транзакции с уровнем изоляции READ_COMMITED также выполняется update, а далее - Thread.sleep(15000). Транзакция **не подтверждена**.
Потом вызывается метод test2(), который при delete() должен ЖДАТЬ, пока предыдущая транзакция будет подтверждена, но вместо этого, она успешно выполняется. Почему?
Почитал документацию про уровни в PostgreSQL. Там вроде четко написано, что операция блокируется на определенной строчке, пока предыдущая транзакция не будет подтверждена, а в итоге получается, что ничего не блокируется. Пример абстрактный, чтобы разобраться

Comment: Дело в том, что в вашем случае с апдейтом, изменения не были  внесены в базу. Если вы сделаете, session.update(test); session.flush(), тогда получите ожидаемый результат - одна транзакция заблочит другую.